# how to remove my synchronised data from my gmail account

Tags: applications, gmail, google-account

I want to remove all data in my Mail Account. I want to delete all contact, image ,whatup-data and any all think which is synchronized in my account. how to remove all information of my Email account any Help please.

Comment: you want to remove it from phone or from email

Comment: remove from email

Comment: This is an Android-independent question. Please visit [help/on-topic] to know what's on-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the **SETTINGS** menu and select the **APPS** option.
2. Select the app from which you want all the data to be removed.
3. Select the **CLEAR DATA** option. This will take a few seconds and all the user data from the app will be deleted.

Comment: It is not my answer. read again question

Comment: Im sorry abhinav. I think you might find your answer over here https://support.google.com/a/answer/173390?hl=en

Comment: no I am not found answer.  I am remove only contact number in my email which was sync  through my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Email account and In top of left and below of Google Click in Gmail and select contact. then show all contact add your account. In there you remove all synchronized contact.